# What is the http.client version or equivalent of requests.get() in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-requests

I just want to know so I can imagine what is going on here.  I used to know that....

what is the equivalent of

```
requests.get('www.awebsite.com')
```

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request)?

Comment: @IainShelvington IDE issues tbh.  Pycharm

Comment: Do the official docs help https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#examples?

Comment: @IainShelvington you ever have beautiful code that works beautifully and then it doesnt?

Comment: No problem. And yes, all the time :)

Comment: @IainShelvington I spent enough hours trying to fix the issue that i realized that I'm better off relearning the basics again...it appears my pycharm just hates the module even after installing

Comment: `urllib.request` is in the standard library and is a higher level module than `http.client`, would make your code a bit cleaner I think

Comment: @IainShelvington trust me, I been trying...

Comment: Just to clarify, `urllib.request` is a module in the standard library and doesn't need to be installed, it is not the same as the `requests` package. Sorry not sure if I wasn't clear before, I don't mean to be rude. This method would do a similar job to what you need https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen

Comment: @IainShelvington you may have saved me lol

Comment: @IainShelvington it worked!